# Reverse integer by using charArray

Tags: java, arrays

What is wrong with my code?
I want to reverse for example 1234 to 4321
It didn't work!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = in.nextInt();

        for (int i =0; i < num; i++){
            int n = in.nextInt();
            char[] ch = ("" + n).toCharArray();
            for (int j = 0; j < ch.length; j ++){
                char temp = ch[j];
                ch[j] = ch[ch.length - 1 -j];
                ch[ch.length - 1 -j] = temp;

                System.out.print(ch + " ");
            }
```

Comment: System.out.print(ch[j] + " "); Will print 1234

Comment: When you're trying an in-place reverse on an array, you have to go only half way, otherwise you'll revert it back. Also, `char[].toString()` doesn't do what you think it does, try `java.util.Arrays.toString` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = in.nextInt();

        for (int i =0; i < num; i++){
            int n = in.nextInt();
            string ch = n.toString();
            string output = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < ch.length; j ++){
                output = ch[j] + output;
            }
            System.out.println(output);
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how ((char)n) works? I have never used it before. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, I just realised that your integer values are likely to be more than single digit so I need to update the answer.

Comment: Yes it is more then one digit.

Comment: ((char)n) would change a number into a character.  However, that would require conversion from numberic to ascii, thus for a '0' it would be an integer value of 48, '1' would be 49, through to 9 which is 57.  If you had an integer value of 1, that is the equivalent of Ctrl-A, not what you want so I have updated the code to reverse the string version of the integer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the easy way to do that i think,

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int num = in.nextInt();
String reverse = new StringBuilder((num + "")).reverse().toString();
System.out.println(reverse);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a few problems in your code:

1. You have get input from user two times.
2. Use `try-with-resource` in `Scanner` to avoid source leak.
3. You have looped over the entire `length` of the array, You need just half of it.
4. You cant print `char[]` array with `toString()`, Because it will return the reference of the array object, You have to loop over array and print on by one, or use `Arrays.toString()`.

---

```
try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    int num = input.nextInt();
    char[] numChars = ("" + num).toCharArray();
    for (int j = 0; j < numChars.length / 2; j++) {
        char temp = numChars[j];
        numChars[j] = numChars[numChars.length - 1 - j];
        numChars[numChars.length - 1 - j] = temp;
    }

    for (char c : numChars) {
        System.out.print(c + " ");
    }
    // Or you can use this instead of the above for loop.
    // System.out.print(Arrays.toString(numChars));
}
```